# webform + form builder: how to clone an existing form

Tags: forms, webforms

I am using webform + form builder to manage some forms on my site.

I can't find a way to clone the form (with all its elements) to a new form?
I know that I can clone elements inside the same form, but I can't export them to another form (and I can't export the form itself).

There is a way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [node clone](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_clone) module to clone that webform node. Then, you will have a new node with webform fields.